# Can I add Keywords to a PDF created with PrintedPDFDocument?

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin

I am in the process of converting a Windows Mobile application to Xamarin Forms, specifically Android. In the Windows Mobile app, we create PDFs using [PDF4NET](http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm) and are able to add Keywords to the Document Information section of the PDF. In the convert to Xamarin Forms (android), I am unable to continue using PDF4NET but I did come across [PrintedPDFDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument). It fits all the requirements so far except for adding Keywords to the Document Information.

I haven't been able to find anywhere in the documentation for PrintedPDFDocument yet about adding keywords and it doesn't look like the object has a property for document information. Is there a special way to do this, or is it not supported at all? If there isn't a way to do Document Information in PrintedPDFDocument, what are some other options I have for PDF generation with Xamarin and Android?

Comment: "what are some other options I have for PDF generation with Xamarin and Android?" - ask your question here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I created a question there as well. I see you work on PDF4NET so I figure I might as well ask; I tried getting PDF4NET to work in a Xamarin forms project - is it possible to get it working, or is it strictly for Compact and Desktop/Server applications?

Comment: strictly desktop/server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up cross posting to [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50904/pdf-library-for-adding-keyword-metadata-to-pdf). Looking at going with XFINIUM for the Android implementation.